# No LC_RPATH's found

Tags: c++, macos, sdl-2, clang++

I'm using mac os sonoma 14.2.1 and xcode-select is fully updated.  I downloaded the .dmg version of SDL2 from the website and put it in /Library/Frameworks.

Heres the code I'm trying to run:

```
// On linux compile with:
// g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o prog -lSDL2

// C++ Standard Libraries
#include <iostream>

// Third-party library
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0){
        std::cout << "SDL could not be initialized: " <<
                  SDL_GetError();
    }else{
        std::cout << "SDL video system is ready to go\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I successfully compiled it with this command:

```
clang++ main.cpp -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2
```

When I run the a.out file I get this error:

```
dyld[995]: Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2
  Referenced from: <AE1C0174-AA36-3B1F-A430-56DE38E61E1B> /Users/<myname>/Desktop/sdl_tutorial/source/1_Introduction_to_SDL/a.out
  Reason: no LC_RPATH's found
zsh: abort      ./a.out
```

I did some research on rpaths but I don't have enough background to fully understand it.  Is this some kind of bug in xcode, clang or macOS?

Comment: Despite your compilation the binary executable remains agnostic as to the location of your third-party framework. I usually give the RPATH after compilation with a separate ‘install_name_tool’ command.

Comment: @RichardBarber could you explain in more detail? I'm a beginner facing this problem and I'm not sure how to do what you've said.